# Connect spark on yarn-cluster in CDH 5.4

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand the "concept" of connecting to a remote server. What I have are 4 servers on CentOS using CDH5.4
What I want to do is connect spark on yarn on all these four nodes.
My problem is I do not understand how to set HADOOP_CONF_DIR as specified [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html). Where and what value should i set for this variable? And then do I need to set this variable on all four nodes or only the master node will suffice?

The documentation says "Ensure that HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster". 
I have read many questions similar to this before asking it in here. Please, let me know what can I do to solve this problem. I am able to run spark and pyspark on stand alone mode on all nodes.

Thanks for your help.
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

> Where and what value should i set for this variable?

The variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR should point to the directory that contains yarn-site.xml. Usually you set it in `~/.bashrc`. I found documentation for CDH.
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Basically all nodes need to have configuration files pointed by the environment variable.

> Once all the necessary configuration is complete, distribute the files to the HADOOP_CONF_DIR directory on all the machines